# Doesn't fade out error message after passing 3 char length

Tags: jquery, onkeyup

```
<form id="createtableform" method="post" action="">
  <p>
    Masa ismi :
    <input type="text" name="name" id="tablename" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
  </p>
</form>
<div id="error"></div>

$('#tablename').focus();
$('#error').fadeOut(500);
$('#tablename').keyup(function(){
var tablename = $('#tablename').length;

if( tablename <= 3){

$('#error').html('Min 3 characters please');
$('#error').fadeIn(500);
}
if( tablename > 3){
$('#error').fadeOut(500);
}
});
```

why doesn't this fade out after i pass 3 chars?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bMJqH/3/

Comment: because $('#tablename').length = 0 or 1 since IDs are unique

Comment: Need to learn to use the built in debugging tools. Chrome is nice and easy- can just add watch elements and break points with no problem. This question is daft.

Answer (score 4):

You're getting the length of the array of matched elements instead of the length of the text inside of the field.

Change:

```
var tablename = $('#tablename').length;
```

To:

```
var tablename = $('#tablename').val().length;
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bMJqH/4/

Also, [have a look at the API](http://api.jquery.com/length/) about the `length` property.

Comment: thank you!!!! i've been coding for so long in one sitting that i can't see little errors like these anymore :S

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('#tablename').keyup(function(){

    var tablename = $('#tablename').val().length;

    if( tablename <= 3){
        $('#error').html('Min 3 characters please');
        $('#error').fadeIn(500);
    } else {
        $('#error').fadeOut(500);
    }

});
```

Comment: @Logan Kevin is 100% right. I post the code that minimize some lines.